What does this line from Frank Herbert's Dune mean?
In the last chapter of Dune, there's this paragraph:

As Stilgar turned to obey, Paul heard the awed muttering of Fremen guards: 'You see? He knew! No one told him, but he knew!'

What are the guards talking about here? What does Paul know that hasn't been told to him?
The preceding paragraph is:

“They come from the ship, the Emperor and his people,” Paul said. “I will stand here. Assemble the captives in an open space in the center of the room. They will be kept at a distance of ten meters from me unless I command otherwise.”

If they were indeed talking about his knowing that the Emperor and his people come from the ship, they'd be wrong because Gurney Halleck already told Muad'Dib that the Emperor was holed up in his ship. So, what are they really referring to?

It is true that Gurney had told Paul that the Emperor was holed in the ship.  The reference is to them approaching him (at that moment).  This is made clear in the next paragraph

The Emperor's entourage could be heard approaching now...


[holed up in the ship]
